# How to resolve tensor size mismatch using pyannote.audio

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to use pyannote's speaker diarization in a project, however I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Expected size 80000 but got size 79659 for tensor number 11 in the list.
```

The code generating this error is simple and follows the TL;DR here: https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio

```py
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline
from env import hugging_face_token
# from pyannote.audio.pipelines import SpeakerDiarization

print('loading pipeline')
pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("pyannote/speaker-diarization",
                                    use_auth_token = hugging_face_token)

print('diarizing')
diarization = pipeline("data/db short intro.ogg")
print('diarizing complete')
```

I'm running this in a docker container using vscode's devcontainer extension.  Here's my devcontainer.json and the contents of requirements.txt

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/python
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:0-3.10",
    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/ffmpeg-apt-get:1": {}
    },
    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    "postCreateCommand": "pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt"
}
```

```
ipython
torch==1.11.0 
torchvision==0.12.0 
torchaudio==0.11.0 
torchtext==0.12.0
speechbrain==0.5.12
pyannote.audio
git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git#egg=openai-whisper
```

I've tried removing the specific versions from requirements.txt and letting it get the latest version of everything but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/m-bain/whisperX/issues/264) it's probably a problem in converting other audio formats to .wav.

you can find the fix at the end of the mentioned discussion.